# Recursive "retains" with different arguments in Gremlin?

Tags: graph, neo4j, gremlin

Based off this question: [Efficient way to find node set having relationships to given nodes using neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956016/efficient-way-to-find-node-set-having-relationships-to-given-nodes-using-neo4j)

and the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011074/881709

I was wondering if you can programmatically chain multiple "retains" with different sets to extend common nodes among 2 nodes to common nodes among n nodes?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Retain is just a pipe, so you can add another retain pipe after the first one. Have you tried it out?